# All WCF services won't start

Tags: wcf

I don't know what the problem is, but I can't start any WCF services?

Even the standard method `GetData` won't work.

They all time out with an error:

> *Cannot obtain Metadata from localhost:9590/Service.svc*

But I didn't change any of the code, and before now all my WCF services worked, but not now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before    deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the    value     below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception   information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But the thing is that i have not made any change to the webconfig. It´s just the standard webconfig, which also work. And also the standard IService.cs and Service.cs. But all my other WCF project also stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Do you add service metadata endpoint in the code or in service Web.config?

Missing metadata endpoint is the only thing i can think of.

Unless you have managed to redirect localhost to somewhere else..

Comment: I have never added metadata endpoints. All have up to this points seems to worked well. I can come up with anything i have done that could mess it up. How do i see if i have redirect localhost??

Comment: Just ping localhost and look for the ip it resolves to. Also i would add mex metadata endpoints. That is probably the main cause of the problem.